# Tuleap after full installation cant able to login

Tags: tuleap

I have installed **Tuleap**(as per full installation from user guide) in CentOS 6.5. All the files got installed. I have tried to login with Tuleap domain name. I gave credentials Login Name and Password : admin / password as generated and clicked on login.
But its not getting login.

The requested URL

> /account/login.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a **404 Not Found error** was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your domain?

If you set your domain name to x and you put y in the address bar the login redirects you to your domain

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [disabling Selinux may be beneficial](https://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html#requirements) for those who encounter this error or one similar on recent installations of Tuleap.

> Currently, Tuleap does not play well with SELinux, you probably want to set SELinux’s behavior to permissive mode to avoid issues.

Interesting though that the login may work in other browsers but not in Firefox. See [this issue request](https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=9950) on Tuleap.

Also try using http://tuleap-server instead of https://tuleap-server. The https will take effect after the login is validated.